# What are the maths problems shown in Good Will Hunting?

Tags: good-will-hunting

I am a big fan of the movie too, and just watched it for the third time.
One thing that intrigues me about this movie is the mathematical problems that are shown.

**First one**

[image]

**Second One**

[image]

Are these any actual theorems/problems from mathematics which are popular or are these just random?

Comment: It's Graph Theory. Try searching on "Graph Theory" and "Good Will Hunting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems shown on the picture are related to graph theory, a subject related to computer science and mathematics [Graph theory on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

The character of Will is inspired by William Sidis you could take a look at his works. [William Sidis Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_James_Sidis).